# Changing a tkinter frame from inside a method/function other than __init__

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, initialization

What im trying to do is find a way to change the Frame from a method/function other than def __init__

My main class which im using to change and manage the Frames with is:

```
class ShopCounter(tk.Tk):

    def __init__ (self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for i in (PageOne, PageTwo):
            frame = i(container, self)
            self.frames[i] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.showFrame(Login)

    def showFrame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
```

The issue im having from here is that when i make a new window such as

```
class PageOne (tk.Frame):
    def __init__ (self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Page 1")
        lbl.pack()
```

This is also in __init__
as this calls the nextPage function (Later shown)
            nextPage()

But i need to read from a CSV spread sheet to check if the person has inputted the user name and pass word (Haven't put checking code or input fields for convenience) i then find that i need to change the frame from a different function in the class PageOne

I have then met the problem of now having to define a controller in this new function s through the parenthesis of the function when it is called which is a problem because i don't know how to do that apart from just putting it as a parameter in the __init__method

Quick example:

Say the function in the class is something like this..

```
def nextPage (self, controller):
    controller.showFrame(PageTwo)
```

IDLE then tells me that i the arguments for this function "controller" is missing but i don't know how I'd set that manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a fix

```
class PageOne (tk.Frame):
    def __init__ (self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Page 1")
        lbl.pack()

        button = tk.Button(self, text="switch", command=lambda: self.launch(controller)
        button.pack()

    def launch (self, cont):
        cont.showFrame(PageTwo)
```

Now I've made a function (launch) in the PageOne class which takes self and cont (the controller) as the parameters. You will then pass the controller from **init** into the launch function when you press the button.

Hope this helps some on. 'Cause personally I've been stumped on this one for months.

## UPDATE

After months of this answer being up, i have now found a new way, rather than always passing the controller as a parameter to each function you with to use in each page class, in the initiation of the class (__ init __), you can declare a variable to the object that holds the controller, heres an example:

```
class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__ (self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller

    def doSomething (self):
        self.controller.doSomething()
```

by referencing the controller you can run any class within the controller class, you can also get variable data and change it.